# Why is my Oracle APEX DML Form stuck in edit mode and not going back to create mode?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a page based on "Form & Report" template. So there is the Report page on which there is the `create` button. That create button leads to the form page which contains.

It is pretty simple. I don't know if there is a cache memory not emptying itself or if there is a setting that I have not properly set.

When I want to create a new database record, Oracle Apex behaves as if I asked it to update a record (though it still presents me with empty text fields).

Below the image of what's happening.

**Create button of the Report**

[image: Image of first form (report form) create button]

**Buttons for edit are shown when I click the create button**

**Those edit buttons are shown instead of the buttons below** => This means that the Apex software is behaving like I asked to edit a record not to insert a record.

[image: Group of images of behavior of DML form (what is happening VS what I would like)]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you already check form buttons display condition and the value in the item used in that validation?

Comment: @hmarques I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean... These forms are create with the RAD feature and I don't really know where I should verify the conditions for form button display or item values....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at your create button. Is it passing a value to the form? If so, you probably don't want that. Is it clearing the cache of the form? If not, you probably want to clear it.

Also, on the form page take a look at your processes.. specifically the Automated Row Fetch (ARF) process.. what's the primary key that this process is using?

Also, take a look at the conditions for each button on your form. For the delete/save buttons you likely want a condition type of "value of item / column in expression 1  Is NOT NULL".

For your create button you would want the opposite.. "value of item /... IS NULL".

In both cases for the expression 1 you'd want to use the item that your ARF is leveraging.

Comment: Hmmmm REALLY strange. I did all that. `create` condition was `But no conditional` I changed it as you said....Still I get the same result...ARF is pointing to the PK column and the correct fiel is set in expression 1 everywhere....that is a realy mystery here

Comment: Ooooookayyyy.... I think (after thinking about you answer) why this happens... Actually, I don't know why but on `insert`, the PK field is not automatically filled with a predefined sequence (in the form creation wizard). So I had to manually tell it that its default value is a seq.NEXVAL..... Now with the condition we set, it will ALWAYS see the manully attributed PK value so it behaves as if we want to perform an update....  I'll try to work it out. But if you have ANY suggestion on how I could deal with that please let me know

Comment: I've solved it. I've checked you answer since it helped me solve it. Thank you mate. Please up vote my question :)

Answer (score 1):

@Bloomberg58 if you used the wizard that should not have  anyway try to validate the create button in report page [image: validate the create button in report page] and the server-side validation of create and save button in form page [image: the server-side validation of create and save button in form page]

Comment: All settings are the same as yours... But for the second picture, I do not see "SERVER-SIDE CONDITION" ...I'm using APEX 4.2.6

Comment: Excellent illustration... I would just like to add that the same "Server-side Condition" is required to be set for the "SAVE" button also